# Limits of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

How do I go about finding the answer to this? I'm not really sure on how to find the general sum formula.
[image]

Comment: Use the squeeze theorem with the bounds$$\frac1{n^2+n\pi}\le\frac1{n^2+k\pi}\le\frac1{n^2}$$

Comment: please tell me how you got those bounds :(

Comment: The LHS is just the lowest term in the summation and the RHS is greater than the greatest term in the summation.

Answer (score 0):

You have that
$$
n\left( {\frac{n}
{{n^2  + n\pi }} +  \cdots \frac{1}
{{n^2  + n\pi }}} \right) < n\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^2  + \pi }} +  \cdots \frac{1}
{{n^2  + n\pi }}} \right) < n\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^2  + \pi }} +  \cdots \frac{1}
{{n^2  + \pi }}} \right)
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{{n^2 }}
{{n^2  + n\pi }} < n\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^2  + \pi }} +  \cdots \frac{1}
{{n^2  + n\pi }}} \right) < \frac{{n^2 }}
{{n^2  + \pi }}
$$
Since
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{n^2 }}
{{n^2  + n\pi }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{n^2 }}
{{n^2  + \pi }} = 1
$$
by squeeze theorem you have that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } n\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^2  + \pi }} +  \cdots \frac{1}
{{n^2  + n\pi }}} \right) = 1
$$